# Adding padding to button pushes other buttons down in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm trying to style a simple button to match the look and feel of a native Windows button.

This does al work in Chrome, but when running in FireFox or Edge (IE), there's some strange behaviour:

See the following css:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

#OfficeUI {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Open Sans";
}

.btn {
  background-color: #E1E1E1;
  border: 1px solid #ADADAD;
  color: #444;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Open Sans";
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 22px;
  min-width: 74px;
  padding: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #E5F1FB;
  border-color: #0078D7;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #CCE4F7;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn-default {
  border-color: #0078D7;
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

and the following Html:

```
<body>
  <div id="OfficeUI">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        Ok
      </button>

      <button type="button" class="btn">
        Ok
      </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

So, the button is normally styled, and when you press down on a button the test shifts 1px down and 1px to the right, to have a kind of pressed effect.

However, when executed in FireFox, the second button is shifted one pixel down, how is that possible?

I've attached a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gdfr2qk/) but fiddle cannot reproduce the problem in Firefox, nor in Edge.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem in Fiddle, then you should be suspicious of the rest of your CSS. Are you using a reset? Include more and more of your code until the Fiddle breaks.

Comment: I can confirm that I've put all my CSS code in JsFiddle and no I'm not using a reset. I would like to understand why I'm having this behaviour rather than using a reset to fix the problem.

Comment: You were right. When I copied your code to a bootstrap file and opened it in Firefox, I was able to reproduce the issue, but not in Fiddle.

Comment: So apparantly we need to watch out when using fiddle.

Comment: The padding for .btn:active should be changed to padding: 0 1px 1px 0; It should do the trick for firefox and will work normally in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a problem with the vertical alignment of the buttons. The browser displays the button as 'inline-block'.
Adding 'vertical-align: top;' fixes the problem.

```
.btn {
      vertical-align: top;
      background-color: #E1E1E1;
      border: 1px solid #ADADAD;
      color: #444;
      font-family: "Segoe UI", "Open Sans";
      font-size: 11px;
      height: 22px;
      min-width: 74px;
      padding: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7gdfr2qk/7/

Comment: Seems to do the trick, however, I don't uderstand why this behaviour is occuring. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Edited my answer. This is because your browser displays the button as 'inline-block'. Inspect the element, click 'calculated' and check 'browser styles'.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know that Inline-Block causes elements to move? :s

Comment: The buttons shift down by one pixel, because of the padding in .btn and .btn:active. The buttons have default vertical-align of 'baseline', aligning them with the baseline of its parent